iPad email outlook trouble shooting
I have an old iPad 2 model A1430 in excellent condition, all apps still run & work perfectly except for the email app. I've tried to research solutions, googled, asked istore etc, but it won't allow me to uninstall, update or reinstate my email app, account etc. The online google email app works but I can't add it to the iPad outlook email accounts. Does anyone know another way to do this and if it can be done?

You cant sign in because IOS sent an invalid request The i get is Error 400 invalid request. You can try again later or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What procedures are you following to delete the app which does not work? I assume you're following Apple's Guidelines?

What OS is on the old iPad?  The first-party email app or something installed from somewhere else?
